# Prove that $ \frac{n^2}{\sum_1^n{\frac{1}{a_i}}} $ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $a_n > 0$ for all $n\geq 1$, and define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}$. If $S_n$ is convergent, prove that 
$$ \frac{n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{a_i}}} $$ 
is also convergent.

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to say "please".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Wikipedia article on [Pythagorean means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means).

Here are some more details. The Wikipedia article tells us that the quantity in question is bounded by the sum. That appears only to give boundedness. Suppose, however, that $\sum_{i=N}^\infty a_i < \epsilon$, and let $C = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i^{-1}$. For $n > N$ we have
$$\frac{(n-N)^2}{\sum_{i=N}^n a_i^{-1}} < \epsilon.$$
In other words,
$$ \sum_{i=N}^n a_i^{-1} > \epsilon^{-1} (n-N)^2. $$
Therefore
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{-1} > C + \epsilon^{-1} (n-N)^2 = \epsilon^{-1}n^2 + o(n^2). $$
So in fact
$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{-1}} < \epsilon. $$
Since this is true for every $\epsilon > 0$, the limit in question is actually $0$.

Comment: Not sure this yields more than the boundedness.

Comment: @Didier That depends on what you do with it.

Comment: Indeed, as the (vastly expanded) new version of your answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Yuval Filmus' proof, but perhaps different enough to be worth considering.

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ converges, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ so that for all $m,n>N$,
$$\sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i<\epsilon$$
Holder's inequality says
$$
\left(\sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}\right)\ge\left(\sum_{i=m+1}^n 1\right)^2=(n-m)^2
$$
Therefore, for all $m,n>N$,
$$
\frac{(n-m)^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}\le\frac{(n-m)^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=m+1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}\le\sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i<\epsilon
$$
Let $n\ge 2m>2N$, then
$$
\frac{n^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}\le 4\frac{(n-m)^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}<4\epsilon
$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\;\frac{n^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}=0
$$